# Как найти параметры запуска приложения в ADB?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При смене пакета

```
com.individual.test
```

на

```
com.popular.test
```

появилась ошибка. AndroidStudio сообщает:

```
Split APKs installed in 3 s 966 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.individual.test/com.popular.test.aMain" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.individual.test/com.popular.test.aMain" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat= [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
 cmp=com.individual.test/com.popular.test.aMain }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.individual.test/com.popular.test.aMain} does not exist.
Error while Launching activity
```

Где находится параметры запуска чтобы это исправить или это надо исправлять как-то иначе?

Comment: посмотрите какой `package` у вас указан в манифесте.

Comment: в манифесте проверил: package="com.popular.test"

Comment: а у активити случаем `name` не равно ли  "com.popular.test.aMain"?

Comment: в общем манифест в студию)

Comment: в поиске по всему проекту, такого слова как individual вообще не найдено.

Comment: После удаления папки Build и перезапуска проекта все заработало!

Comment: Только хотел это посоветовать... А про параметры запуска из студии см. здесь: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig